# Setting folder permissions returns "Access Denied"

Tags: windows, permissions, windows-server-2008

I'm trying to change the permissions on a folder on my windows 2008 server. The problem is that my account "admin" was set to not have any privileges. Also stripped of privileges is the "Creator" role. Is there a way to override this? I've never had to get around the admin account before.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possibly edit folder permissions via powershell:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johan/2008/10/01/powershell-editing-permissions-on-a-file-or-folder/

Hope this helps!